# qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped while using buildx on amd for building arm image

Tags: linux, docker, qemu, buildx

I am trying to build `arm64` image on my `x86_64` machine using `buildx` and I have encountered `qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped` Error.

#### Machine Description

```
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9900 CPU @ 3.10GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1376MHz
          capacity: 5GHz
          width: 64 bits
```

OS: `ubuntu:18:04`

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.8
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.6
 Git commit:        3967b7d
 Built:             Fri Jul 30 19:54:08 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.8
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.6
  Git commit:       75249d8
  Built:            Fri Jul 30 19:52:16 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.10
  GitCommit:        8848fdb7c4ae3815afcc990a8a99d663dda1b590
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Create a Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Install packages
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
```

2. Run binfmt container

```
docker run --rm --privileged docker/binfmt:820fdd95a9972a5308930a2bdfb8573dd4447ad3
```

3. Setup new builder

```
$ docker buildx create --name mybuilder
$ docker buildx use mybuilder
$ docker buildx inspect --bootstrap
```

4. Build Image

```
$ docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 --push -t user/failure-case .
```

#### Error Trace

```
#25 133.4 Setting up libpython3-dev:arm64 (3.9.2-3) ...
#25 133.5 Setting up python3-dev (3.9.2-3) ...
#25 133.5 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u3) ...
#25 133.5 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
#25 133.6 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
#25 133.6 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
#25 133.8 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
#25 133.8 dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
#25 133.8  installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
#25 133.8 Errors were encountered while processing:
#25 133.8  libc-bin
#25 133.9 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
Dockerfile:7
--------------------
  12 |
  13 |     RUN apt update
  14 | >>> RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
  15 |     #Python requirements
  16 |     RUN pip3 install \
--------------------
error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python3-pip" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Feel free to ask for more info. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue due to qemu. `qemu` older was resulting in above failure and updating `qemu` version to `7.0.0` solved the issue for me.

You can check following article [Building ARM/Jetson image on x86 linux machine using docker buildx](https://medium.com/@pranjaldoshi96/building-arm-jetson-image-on-x86-linux-machine-using-docker-buildx-752293ce9c90)

Basically update your qemu version

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install make -y
sudo apt install ninja-build -y
sudo apt-get install libpixman-1-dev
wget https://download.qemu.org/qemu-7.0.0.tar.xz
tar xvJf qemu-7.0.0.tar.xz
cd qemu-7.0.0/
./configure
make
docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt --install all
export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled
```

Now use docker `buildx` to build the image with platform as `linux/arm64`

Comment: Dont we have to run `make install`. I followed your steps, but still `kvm -version` prints `QEMU emulator version 4.2.1 (Debian 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.28)`, though I have downloaded qemu 7. As per this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1147323/111621), we have to run `make install`. After running `sudo make install` from qemu's build folder, it started showing version `QEMU emulator version 7.0.0`. But `/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 --version` stills says `QEMU emulator version 4.2.1 (Debian 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.28)`